# .NET Standard 2.1 vs .NET Core 3.1 Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard

I have the following 2 projects :

```
ConsoleApp (.Net Core 3.1)
DataLoaderLib (.Net Standard 2.1)
```

DataLoaderLib uses System.Web.Services, which I know is not available in .NET Core.
(Originally this project was in .NET Framework but I moved it to .NET Standard so I could reference it in my .NET Core project.)

So ...ConsoleApp references DataLoaderLib, and DataLoaderLib references System.Web.Services.

However when I run my ConsoleApp I get the following error message.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)'
```

I can see the System.Web.Services.dll in the output directory, so I don't think that it can't find the file.

My understanding was that I could use libraries from .NET Framework if they moved to a .NET Standard project.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"My understanding was that I could use libraries from .NET Framework if they moved to a .NET Standard project."_ - you can try, but nobody can guarantee that it will work (especially when you will try to deploy to non-Windows platforms).

Comment: Remove the reference to System.Web.Services.  Add it back with the Browse option, selecting the one in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 instead.  Do start thinking about migrating the code that requires it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding was that I could use libraries from .NET Framework if they moved to a .NET Standard project.

Nope; this is not the case - .NET Standard is just a set of API filters / definitions that is *expected* to be provided and available on any runtime that implements that .NET Standard. If your library restricts itself to just .NET Standard 2.0 APIs, then it *should* work on .NET Core 3.1 or above, and .NET Framework 4.6.2 or above (IIRC), and any other .NET Standard 2 implementation (Unity, maybe).

However, the moment you reference a .NET Framework specific library: all bets are off. That library could be trying to call other framework bits *that don't exist* on .NET Core (or have moved, etc), or could be trying to access OS features via APIs that *don't exist* outside of a specific Windows runtime. The setup you describe would *probably* work if you ran it on .NET Framework, simply because everything at runtime would be in place - but: on any other runtime: dice roll.

> What am I doing wrong?

Referencing a .NET Framework specific assembly from a project that targets .NET Standard. You must restrict yourself to libraries that *themselves* target .NET Standard. In reality, targeting .NET Standard is over-rated; IMO it is usually more useful and pragmatic to multi-target *runtimes*, for example you could multi-target some version(s) of .NET Framework and .NET Core / later, and use the *correct and known* implementations, rather than the .NET Standard API.